# How do I tell my graph coloring problem program to only assign color 1 one time?

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

Basically, I have a graph coloring program where each node with an edge to another node has to be different colors. Here, is my code:

```
node(1..4).

edge(1,2).
edge(2,3).
edge(3,4).
edge(4,1).
edge(2,4).

color(1..3).

{ assign(N,C) : color(C) } = 1 :- node(N).

1 { assign(N,1) : color(1) } 1 :- node(N). %line in question

:- edge(N,M), assign(N,C), assign(M,C).
```

How would I tell the program to only assign color 1, once? The line labeled %line in question is the line giving me problems. Here is another solution I tried that didn't work:

```
node(1..4).

edge(1,2).
edge(2,3).
edge(3,4).
edge(4,1).
edge(2,4).

color(1..3).

{ assign(N,C) : color(C) } = 1 :- node(N).

:- edge(N,M), assign(N,C), assign(M,C).

vtx(Node, Color) :- node(Node), color(Color).

1 { vtx(N, 1) : color(1) } 1 :- node(N).

#show vtx/2.
```

If anyone could help me out it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this simple case of restricting a single color to be used once, you can write the a single constraint

```
:- assign(N, 1), assign(M, 1), node(N), node(M), N!=M.
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the line you marked as **in question** :

```
1 { assign(N,1) : color(1) } 1 :- node(N). %line in question
```

can be translated as

> **If `N` is a node, we will (and we must) assign `color(1)` to `node(N)` and only assign once**, i.e. **If `node(i)` is true, we will have exactly one `node(i, 1)`.**

Therefore, with this rule and your facts `node(1..4)`, you will immediately get `assign(1,1)`, `assign(2,1)`, `assign(3,1)`, `assign(4,1)`. This is defninitely unsatisfiable under color problem (with the last constraint).

Back to your requirement:

> How would I tell the program to only assign color 1, once?

The problem here is the constraint you set in the line: "**color 1 is assigned only once**" applies to each `node(i), i=1,2,3,4` instead of all nodes.

To make it clearer, you might as well consider that this line would be instantiated as:

```
1 { assign(1,1) : color(1) } 1 :- node(1). 
1 { assign(2,1) : color(1) } 1 :- node(2). 
1 { assign(3,1) : color(1) } 1 :- node(3). 
1 { assign(4,1) : color(1) } 1 :- node(4).
```

With `node(1..4)` all true, we will have `assign(1,1)`, `assign(2,1)`, `assign(3,1)`, `assign(4,1)`.

What you want is `assign(N, 1)` appears once and only once in the answer, thus in your rule, this should be true with no premiere condition.

Therefore, change the problem line into:

```
{ assign(N,1): node(N), color(1) } = 1. %problem line changed
```

You will get the proper assignment:

```
clingo version 5.4.0
Reading from test.lp
Solving...
Answer: 1
assign(2,2) assign(1,3) assign(3,3) assign(4,1)
Answer: 2
assign(1,2) assign(2,3) assign(3,2) assign(4,1)
Answer: 3
assign(2,1) assign(1,3) assign(3,3) assign(4,2)
Answer: 4
assign(2,1) assign(1,2) assign(3,2) assign(4,3)
SATISFIABLE
```

Intuitively, this line means the `assign(N, 1)` should be in answer set under no condition, as long as `N` is a node. This will count all nodes instead of every single one.